# MixItUp & Simple Parallax Scrolling

Tags: parallax

Использую на сайте два плагина, [MixitUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/) и [Simple Parallax Scrolling](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/).

Использую две секции, в первой плагин сортировки с плитками (MixitUps), во второй, которая ниже, — параллакс. При загрузке страницы параллакс работает, но если начать сортировать плитки, то у секции с этими плитками меняется высота контейнера, и плагин параллакса не может высчитать необходимую ему высоту для корректного отображения, и, соответственно, он исчезает или уходит вниз/вверх.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, в обеих плагинах это есть в документации, решил таким образом:

```html
$('#shop_grid').mixItUp({
  callbacks: {
  onMixEnd: function(){
   $(window).trigger('resize').trigger('scroll');
  }
 }
});
```